# Asterisk must connect to voicemail with N number of extensions

Tags: asterisk

Can the voicemail message path be specified in `voicemail.conf`?

I tried and ended up in `VM_MESSAGEFILE`.

I want to know whether `_XXXX` can be used in `voicemail.conf`.

I need to store all of the registered sip users.

through static we can give one by one. what if i want to create 100 plus mailbox users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use database-driven list of users.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+voicemail+database

In database you can use view and/or function to create dummy list of users.